# how do I use a gravatar image as a link using gravatar_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I know this is a simple question yet I cannot figure out how to do it. I want to use a gravatar_for attendee and have the gravatar link_to the attendee. Just using the gravatar with no link works like this:

```
<%= gravatar_for attendee, :size => 35 %>
```

Great. but every time I try to add a link I break it or it doesn't appear correctly. I tried this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(gravatar_for attendee, :size => 35) %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is probably with your parentheses. Try:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(gravatar_for(attendee, :size => 35)) %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: <%= link_to gravatar_for(attendee, :size => 35, :alt => attendee) %>